# WH_KEYBOARD_LL doesn't fire in fullscreen games

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, global, record

I wanted to capture keyboard input globally to create some kind of macro-application so I went and did some research to see if it was doable.

I ended up here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook which seemed to work perfectly, the only problem is that the keyboard hook does not fire when I'm playing a fullscreen ( DirectX ) game, is there some workaround to still capture keyboard input even in a fullscreen game?

Comment: Games normally use raw input, it bypasses a hook.  So this is pretty normal.

Comment: @Hans know of another way to capture this input?